# Combine First and Last Name in View RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm coding my first rails project, and about halfway through realized that I needed to have first name and last name as an input when creating certain users from an administrative screen. The reason for this is so that those users can have their password automatically set to their last name, and then have a password reset option on first login. However, my Users table contains only name:string, and I don't want to change that into first and last name columns (that was the smart thing to have at the beginning, but now that I've already built other forms for Users, it would be really annoying to refactor). I've been messing around with different ways to combine the fields in form_for, but none have worked so far (some are present in my code). Ideas?

To clarify, I am not looking for anything that changes the user.rb file to require a user to have a first name or a last name.

admins_controller:

```
def newchair
  params[:user][:name] = "#{params[:first]} #{params[:last]}"
  params[:user][:password] = "#{params[:last]}"
  params[:user][:password_confirmation] = "#{params[:last]}"
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to '/admin/chair'
  else
    redirect_to '/admin/chair'
  end
end
...
private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :access_level,
                               :phone_number)
  end
```

chairs.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <input type="text" name="first" id="first" />

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <input type="text" name="last" id="last" />



      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :access_level, :value => "Chair" %>

      <%= f.label :Phone %>
      <%= f.telephone_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Console Output (name does not appear in the "user" params list):

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"THo/nkIFuQhD16ql+QKwnLoYRbSiKR371ptcRXx5XKJtt761m6To+7nUWes2+LLJsyicTXMUozlO+npiLg2HUg==", "first"=>"Blah", "last"=>"Blah", "user"=>{"email"=>"blah1@example.com", "access_level"=>"Chair", "phone_number"=>"(914) 980-3233"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: By experience, I can tell you it may end up being a terrible bad idea in the long term not to have separate `first_name` and `last_name` fields. Mostly because of irreversibility : it becomes almost impossible to retrieve the first/last name from the `full_name` if you ever need it (some people have composite names with whitespaces...). Now I understand it could be complicated to migrate from `name` to `first_name` and `last_name` but it could save you some troubles in the future...

Comment: Thanks @CyrilDD yeah I will probably end up doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as using

```
params[:user][:name] = "#{params[:first]} #{params[:last]}"
```

No need to really merge when you are just adding one key, and then I use string interpolation to make the string concatenation a little easier to read.

Comment: Where would I put this line of code? My updated code above still produces the erroneous output (which I've added)

Comment: You can put this line at the beginning of the `user_params` function for example. But don't forget to add nil checks, otherwise this line may crash your app !